# How to create a flashing pointer effect to UIImages in Swift

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, uiimageview, uiimage

I'm trying to create a pointer effect in Swift. I have six UIImageView each has a UIImage that are ordered in a circular way. I want to create an animation of having each image flash (as if it's a pointer indication) for a certain duration.

I thought of creating an array with a transparent version of the images and then create an animated sequence from them but the duration gets mixed up.

This is the idea I'm trying to achieve. I want the images to kind of have this flashing effect, one by one.

[image: idea description]

Comment: What is the issue you are having? What have you tried?

Comment: @Brandon I've tried creating an animatedImage for each UIImage, but I cant get the duration to be consistent because they end up overlapping in time with several of them having the pointer image when it's supposed to be one by one.

Comment: Do you know about CAReplicatorLayer? https://developer.apple.com/documentation/quartzcore/careplicatorlayer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

This is how I accomplished placing views in a circle and making them "flash"..

- First I created regular views (I didn't want to use ImageView's but you are okay to change the code however you like)..
- I calculated the angle at which the views need to be placed around a centre point with some radius.. to get them to place in a circle.
- Next I create an animation function which has both a forward and reverse animation (I couldn't get `autoreverses` flag to work)..
- To get one to display after the other, I simply add a delay (x2 because forward + reverse)..
- To figure out when ALL animations have completed, I wrapped the entire function in a `CATransaction`.

**Note:** If you don't need the circular placement code, simply remove it. AFAIK, you only need the animation code.

```
//
//  ViewController.swift
//  TestSO
//
//  Created by Brandon on 2018-03-03.
//  Copyright © 2018 XIO. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit

extension UIColor {
    class func random() -> UIColor {
        let rand = { (max: CGFloat) -> CGFloat in
            let rnd = CGFloat(arc4random()) / CGFloat(UInt32.max)
            return rnd * max
        }

        return UIColor(red: rand(1.0), green: rand(1.0), blue: rand(1.0), alpha: 1.0)
    }
}

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let makeView = { () -> UIView in
            let view = UIView()
            view.backgroundColor = UIColor.random()
            view.frame = CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: 50.0, height: 50.0)
            self.view.addSubview(view)
            return view
        }

        let imageViews = [
            makeView(),
            makeView(),
            makeView(),
            makeView(),
            makeView(),
            makeView()
        ]

        let locationForView = { (angle: CGFloat, center: CGPoint, radius: CGFloat) -> CGPoint in
            let angle = angle * CGFloat.pi / 180.0
            return CGPoint(x: center.x - radius * cos(angle), y: center.y + radius * sin(angle))
        }

        for i in 0..<imageViews.count {
            let center = self.view.center
            let radius = ((150.0 + imageViews[i].bounds.size.width) / 2.0)
            let count = imageViews.count
            imageViews[i].center = locationForView(((360.0 / CGFloat(count)) * CGFloat(i)) + 90.0, center, radius)
        }

        self.animate(views: imageViews.reversed(), duration: 3.0, intervalDelay: 0.5)
    }

    private func animate(views: [UIView], duration: TimeInterval, intervalDelay: TimeInterval) {

        CATransaction.begin()
        CATransaction.setCompletionBlock {
            print("COMPLETED ALL ANIMATIONS")
        }

        var delay: TimeInterval = 0.0
        let interval = duration / TimeInterval(views.count)

        for view in views {
            let colour = view.backgroundColor
            let transform = view.transform

            UIView.animate(withDuration: interval, delay: delay, options: [.curveEaseIn], animations: {

                view.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
                view.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1.2, y: 1.2)

            }, completion: { (finished) in

                UIView.animate(withDuration: interval, delay: 0.0, options: [.curveEaseIn], animations: {

                    view.backgroundColor = colour
                    view.transform = transform

                }, completion: { (finished) in


                })
            })

            delay += (interval * 2.0) + intervalDelay
        }
        CATransaction.commit()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


}
```

Comment: You are a lifesaver! Thank you so much.

Comment: I've been trying to figure out how to make this animation repeat itself for several defined times. In other words, I want this flashing to be repeated in the circle. Can you please help me with that?